# How can I turn off git bash for Windows case-insensitive behavior?

Tags: bash, windows, case-sensitivity

I use the [Git Bash on Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) for numerous bash tasks exceeding the Git use. It works well over years, but I cannot turn of the case-insensitive behavior. Auto-complete is cumbersome this way.

I tried the flag

```bash
shopt -u nocasematch
```

in the `.bashrc` as described [in solution #3](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Dealing_with_case_sensitive_pattern) but it does not resolve the issue.

Neither solution #1 or #2 are an option for what I am looking for, as I have aliases uppercase, directories mixed cases and some files all lowercase and it is too many cases to apply a case-map.

Is there any way to enable case-sensitive autocomplete in my non-default Linux shell?

Since it is a different flavor, I would appreciate some hints or suggestions.

Comment: Isn't NTFS case insensitive?

Comment: @memchr it's case-memorable case-insensitive

Comment: @roaima Yes, but MSYS2 uses the Windows API, which threads filenames in a case-insensitive manner. could this be the cause?

Comment: @memchr just got back to my desk to check. An NTFS filesystem mounted on a Linux-based OS is case-sensitive (I've got `Abc`, `aBC`, and `abc` as separate files). That same filesystem on a Windows system is treated as case-insensitive and only one of the three files is accessible (an attempt to open any of the three files returns just the "first" one).

Comment: thanks @roaima, so the problem itself is when I am working with linux commands on my windows directories due to the NTFS being case-insensitive there is no way to force the linux syntax to be case-sensitive as the data itself is not. Whatever happens in the background when mapping NTFS/EXT4, this mapping cannot differentiate between case-sensitivity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to revert two settings, `nocaseglob` and `nocasematch`:

The documentation (`man bash`) writes,

> **`nocaseglob`** If  set,`bash` matches  filenames in a case-insensitive fashion when performing pathname expansion […]
>
> **`nocasematch`**  If  set, `bash` matches  patterns  in a case-insensitive fashion when performing matching while executing `case` or `[[` conditional commands, when performing pattern substitution word expansions, or when filtering possible  completions as part of programmable completion.

For my Cygwin environment these are both set `off` (although arguably both should be `on` for Windows-centric use of an NTFS filesystem, which expects case-memorable but case-insensitive<sup>*</sup>):

```
shopt | grep case
nocaseglob      off
nocasematch     off
```

If these are set `on` in your environment and you want them disabled (so that comparisons are made case-sensitively), you may want to try this command

```
shopt -u nocasematch nocaseglob
```

I should point out though that this may not work. An NTFS filesystem mounted on a Linux-based OS is case-sensitive (I can create and access `Abc`, `aBC`, and `abc` as separate files). That same filesystem on a Windows system is treated as case-insensitive and only one of the three files is accessible from File Explorer or Cygwin (an attempt to open any of the three files returns just the "first" one). I suspect this level of detail is beyond your requirement but I'm just adding it in case it's useful.

[Additional information](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html#pathnames-casesensitive) from Cygwin, which *I have not tested* as it seems to enforce the opposite configuration to that which you want:

> **Case sensitive filenames**
> In the Win32 subsystem filenames are only case-preserved, but not case-sensitive. You can't access two files in the same directory which only differ by case, like Abc and aBc. While NTFS (and some remote filesystems) support case-sensitivity, the NT kernel does not support it by default. Rather, you have to tweak a registry setting and reboot. For that reason, case-sensitivity can not be supported by Cygwin, unless you change that registry value.
>
> If you really want case-sensitivity in Cygwin, you can switch it on by setting the registry value `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\obcaseinsensitive`
> to 0 and reboot the machine.

As a different angle, [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) autocompletes based on case-sensitivity. If I have a directory `Downloads` and a directory `dances`, then `ls -d D`<kbd>Tab</kbd> only offers the one directory, which I think is the behaviour that you want. If you're not absolutely wedded to Git bash you might want to try Cygwin with its `git` package.

---

<sup>* NTFS itself is case-sensitive. However, when used in a Windows environment it appears to be case-memorable but case-insensitive, so that's what we have to work with.</sup>

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to elaborate on this, I might test this with the registry as I did apply both flags and sourced the `.bashrc` new, but when I write UPP I still get mixed case and lowercase autocomplete options.
I need to backup my registry first :)